Help with Evaluating a Limit Involving Alternating Series $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^k (k+1)(k+2)}{2N} $
Hello Math StackExchange community,
I'm having some trouble evaluating the following limit:
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^k (k+1)(k+2)}{2N}
$$
I've attempted to approach this limit by splitting the sum into two separate sums, one for even values of k and one for odd values of k, but I haven't made much progress beyond that.
Does anyone have any insights or techniques that could be useful in evaluating this limit?
Thank you in advance!

You can start with
$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x^{k+1} = \frac{x(1-x^N)}{1-x}$$
and differentiating,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (k+1)x^{k} = \frac{1 - (1 + N) x^N + N x^{1 + N}}{( x-1)^2}$$
multiplying by $x^2$ and differentiating again, then put $x=-1$. However, you limit tend to infinity given that you will get a polynomial on $N$ in the numerator of a higher degree than the denominator

@Bertrand87: thank you!! Your comment has been helpful, I solved the question

Is the numerator meant to be $2N^2$?

Since
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+r}{r}x^k=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r+1}}\quad (r\geq0)
$$
where $r$ is an integer it follows that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^k (k+1)(k+2)=2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(-1)^k\binom{k+2}{2}=2[x^{N-1}]\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\times\frac{1}{(1+x)^3}\right) = 
2[x^{N-1}]\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\times\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)
$$
where $[x^m]f(x)$ extracts the coefficient of $x^m$ in the power series for $f$. Since
$$
\frac{1}{1-x^2} = 1+x^2+x^4+\dotsb
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=1-2x+3x^2+\dotsb
$$
the coefficient of $x^{N-1}$ in the above product will oscillate between a negative sum of even integers and positive sum of odd integers both of which are of $O(N^2)$. So the desired limit doesn't exist. The argument just given can be made more precise.

Let's start by evaluating the numerator. Define an operator $$T_n(\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{n-1}) = T_n(\{a_k\}) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k a_{k},$$
then
$$\begin{align*} 
2T_n(\{a_k\}) &= \left(a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k a_{k}\right)+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k a_{k}+(-1)^{n-1} a_{n-1}\right) \\ 
&=a_0+(-1)^{n-1} a_{n-1}+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k a_{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k a_{k}\right) \\
&= a_0+(-1)^{n-1} a_{n-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k\left( a_{k+1}-a_k\right) \\
T_n(\{a_k\})  &= \frac{1}{2}\big( a_0+(-1)^{n-1} a_{n-1}\big)-\frac{1}{2}T_{n-1}(\{a_{k+1}-a_k\}).
\end{align*}$$
Therefore $T_n(\{2\}) = 1 - (-1)^n$, $$T_n(\{k\}) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}(n-1)-\frac{1}{2}T_{n-1}(\{1\}) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}(n-1)-\frac{1}{4}(1+(-1)^n)$$
and for $n\ge 2$, $$\begin{gather*} T_n(\{ k^2 \}) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}(n-1)^2-\frac{1}{2}T_{n-1}(\{2k+1\})\\
 = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}(n-1)^2-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}\big(1+(-1)^n(2n-3) \big)-\frac{1}{2}T_{n-2}(\{2\}) \right] \\
= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2}(n-1)^2-\frac{1}{4}\big(1+(-1)^n(2n-3) \big)+\frac{1}{4}\big(1 - (-1)^n \big).\end{gather*}$$
Now the limit is given by $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T_n(\{k^2\})+3T_n(\{k\})+T_n(\{2\})}{2n} = D.N.E$$
as it alternates between $\pm \infty$. $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{T_n(\{k^2\})+3T_n(\{k\})+T_n(\{2\})}{2n^2} \right| = \frac{1}{4}$$
